# Automatically insert timestamp when opening certain file

Tags: autocmd

I'd like to have the timestamp inserted on a new line every time I open a certain file.

I see that `put =strftime('%c')` is the command that I want, and that putting that command into a file, say `pjf.vim`  - and then into the folder `.vim/ftplugin/` should do the trick. But unfortunately, it doesn't.

`autocmd` almost does what I want - but with :

`autocmd VimEnter *.pjf pu=strftime('%c')` - it puts the timestamp at the top of the file...

Anyone have any clues?

Comment: Have you looked into [`autocmd`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#%3Aautocmd)s at all? That'd be the way I would go about something like this.

Comment: yeah I was just about to edit and say that autocmd is almost doing it - but not quite...

Comment: You want it on the last line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were very close. You just need to add `$` to your put command.

```
autocmd VimEnter *.pjf $pu=strftime('%c')
```

`put` can take a line argument. This can be a line number or `$` for end of file.

See [`:help :put`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#%3Aput) for more info.

Comment: Awesome! I wound using a little function, but this is better/cleaner.

Comment: What does the `=` do? I can't see anything related in the `:put` doc

Comment: @SridharSarnobat From the `:put` documentation:
"The register can also be '=' followed by an optional expression.  The expression continues until the end of the command."